# how to insert my html form data to my database using restfulwebservice in eclipse

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, eclipse, web-services

created a resful webservice for login authentication and accessed it using ajax..
now i have to insert a form data to my webservice can anyone help me with it.. my form contains `

```
issueid, date, status, description
```

on clicking submit button it should go to my database using webservice..

my authentication code is:

```
@Path("/authentication")
public class AuthLogin {

    @POST 
    @Path("/info/{username}/{password}") 
    @Produces("text/plain") 
    public String responseMsg(
        @PathParam("username") String uname,
        @PathParam("password") String pwd ) throws SQLException {

    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String isuservalid = null;
    try { 
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:my server details);
        String query = "checkAMISUser '" + uname + "' , '" + pwd +"'";
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs != null && rs.next()) {
            isuservalid = rs.getString("STATUS");
        }
   } catch (Exception err) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: " + err);
   } finally {
        rs.close();
        conn.close();
   }
   Response.ok().header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
   return isuservalid;
   }
}
```

my ajax call is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uname = $("#userid").val();
    $(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#projectpage",function() {
       uname = $("#userid").val();
       var pwd = $("#password").val();
       var serviceurl= "http://myhost/Authentication/rest/authentication/info";
    $.ajax({
        url:serviceurl + '/' +uname +'/' +pwd,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function(data) {
            if(data=='True') {
                alert("Web service call succeeded." );
            else{
                alert("Invalid UserName and Password");
                $.mobile.changePage('#loginpage');
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('ERROR has occurred!');alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
     })
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Not able to read the code properly.....!

Comment: i dont know how to edit it.. can u edit it properly

Comment: What is your REST layer? Jersey? Spring? Something else?

Are you getting a specific error message when you try to execute this?

Comment: jersy.. i executed got it well.. now i want to insert record to my database procedure.. dont know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html#calling_javadb_mysql

and adapt for microsoft DB (which I assume you're using because of your JDBC driver namespace. Pay special attention to how they make the call using '?' and variable replacements, this protects you from database injections.

If you try that and get stuck again, please provide the exception being thrown and as much of the stack trace as you can ethically (without revealing proprietary information).